# IIS6 won't respond to a request for a JS file after accessing through subdomain

Tags: iis, javascript, not-responding

I have a site running of www.mysite.com for example.

There is a JS file I'm accessing: www.mysite.com/packages.js

The first and subsequent times that I acccess that packages.js file causes no problems........until I access a sub-site like this:

sub-site.mysite.com

This naturally makes a request for that same packages.js....but the site hangs as it just keeps waiting and waiting for that JS file.

Going back to the main site, the problem perists there.

If I then rename packages.js to say packages2.js it then works in the same way. I can access the file on the main site but after I try and access it through a sub-site IIS then fails to respond to a request for that file.

I realise this explanation is a little vague, but has anyone seen this sort of behaviour before?

Thanks very much,

James.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a caching or proxy issue.  Try out firebug in Firefox, or Fiddler2.  Those tools will allow you to get a better handle on what's happening between the client and server.  Also, check the IIS log files to see what status request it's returning.  That can often give further hints that will help in narrowing this down.